# Isomorphism between Fundamental Group and $\mathbb Z$

Tags: analysis, homotopy-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to show that
$$f: \pi_1(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},1) \to \mathbb Z$$
with
$$[a] \to n(a,0)$$
($n(a,0)$ being the winding number of $a$ in $0$) is an isomorphism.

So basically, all I have to do is to show the following things:

**1) $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},1)$ with $[a][b]=[ab]$ and  $\mathbb Z$ with $+$ are groups.**

**2) $f$ is well-defined.**

I've already shown 1) and 2), but now I'm having a problem with the other properties:

**3) $f$ is injective.**

Let $f([a])=f([b])$ for $[a],[b] \in \pi_1(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},1)$. This implies that the winding numbers of a and b are the same, so basically $n(a,0)=n(b,0)$. I know that for all closed curves the winding number is $0$. Does this already show 3)?

**4) $f$ is surjective.**

**5) $f$ is a homomorphism.**

Could someone help me with the last three properties?

Comment: For $(4)$, you just need to give a loop in $(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}, 1)$ that has a winding number $n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. For example, $\gamma(t) = e^{2 \pi i n t}$ will do (where the domain of $\gamma$ is $[0,1]$). Property $(5)$ will follow from the additivity of the integral and a change of variables. However, $(3)$ is more delicate. Do you know that $\pi_1(S^1, 1) \approx \mathbb{Z}$ or anything about covering spaces?

Comment: @levap I will try to solve $(4)$ and $(5)$ and see, if I can come up with something. Thanks for the hints. Regarding $(3)$, I'm afraid, I don't know either. Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: You can see a direct argument in page 297 of Ahlfor's complex analysis book.

Comment: @levap There is more than one Ahlfor book with that title. Which one do you mean exactly?

Comment: This one: https://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Lars-Ahlfors/dp/0070006571.

Comment: @levap Alright, I found it. Thanks a lot!